# Label not associated to input

Tags: html, forms, validation, accessibility, lighthouse

Using the built in Chrome Lighthouse to run accessibility audit on a WP site showed the signup field as being invalid due to no associated label. I've run into this before and I can't understand why it doesn't think it's associated. I can get it to pass by adding an `aria-label` tag to the `input` directly but I shouldn't have to do that.

Here is a code snippet that is created from Subscribe2

```
<label for="s2email">Your email:</label>
<br>
<input type="text" name="email" id="s2email" value="Enter email address..." size="20" onfocus="if (this.value === 'Enter email address...') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value === '') {this.value = 'Enter email address...';}">
```

Can be found here: https://blog.collaborative.org/

Comment: Something is missing from your example.  If I copy/paste your sample into a simple page, it passes lighthouse (and axe).  The <label> correctly points to the <input>.  I usually see problems when the <input> has a NAME attribute but not an ID attribute.  That is, the <label> points to "s3email" but the <input> has `name="s2email"` (which is for javascript) and doesn't have `id="s2email"`.

Comment: Note also that your `onfocus` is pointing to a string instead of a function.  That's another hint that you might have typed the code sample instead of copy/pasting the original code that has the problem.  I'm assuming you don't really have an `on` handler pointing to a string.

Comment: The for/id relationship looks correct here. Can we see the actual page, to look at the whole context? Or, can you provide the exact report that the tool provided?

Comment: Are the IDs unique? If there are two inputs with the same ID that could cause this.

Comment: Sure, I had stripped it apart a little to simplify it. Will update OP.

Comment: ID is not duplicated anywhere on the page.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you look at the code sample in isolation, it looks fine: it has a `label` explicitly associated with the `input` element using the `for` and `id` attributes.

However, when you inspect the site, it looks different: due to the style rule `.s2_form_widget label { display: none; }` the label is invisible. (You can see this when you use the Inspector in Firefox, move to the label in the DOM tree and check the associated styles.)

Note that `display: none` does not only hide the label visually but also for screen readers. As a result, the input element has no label from the point of view of a screen reader or another assistive technology and fails the requirement that form controls need explicit labels. (As an alternative, you might try hiding the label off-screen with a negative margin.)

Comment: Ahh that makes sense! I'll adjust that and test.

Comment: negative margin doesn't work for me. Are there any ways to suppress that error?

Comment: @JSmith Can you please post that as a separate question? (Hiding things off-screen using negative margins is a documented technique.)

Comment: @JSmith See e.g. [CSS in Action](https://webaim.org/techniques/css/invisiblecontent/) on the WebAIM site.